# SQL Server Stored Procedure Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am not really a SQL man, so I'm struggling. What is wrong with `"program"` below that is preventing me from creating this stored procedure? Any help or clean up suggestions would be great.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateHaystackExportJob_Program]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ID AS VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @JobCount AS INT

    SELECT 
        @JobCount = COUNT (*) 
    FROM 
        dbo.HaystackExportJobs
    WHERE 
        ID = @ID AND ExportType = "program" 

    IF @JobCount = 0
        INSERT INTO dbo.HaystackExportJobs (ID,ExportType) VALUES (@ID,"program")

END
```

Comment: You'll get much better feedback if you post error messges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Odd things:**

1. the parameter is declared varchar without a size.
2. Can't use quotes to encapsulate strings. You need to use aprostrophes.

Answer (score 5):

A few things, first you should include a length on the `@id` parameter.

Second, string values in SQL Server should be in single quotes so remove the double quotes and replace them with single quotes around `"program"`. So your code will be similar to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateHaystackExportJob_Program]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ID AS VARCHAR(50) -- place a length on this parameter or an int if this is numeric
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @JobCount AS INT

    SELECT 
        @JobCount = COUNT (*) 
    FROM 
        dbo.HaystackExportJobs
    WHERE 
        ID = @ID 
        AND ExportType = 'program' 

    IF @JobCount = 0
        INSERT INTO dbo.HaystackExportJobs (ID,ExportType) 
        VALUES (@ID,'program')

END
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58987)

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes, not double quotes.  Here is an example of where you use double quotes.  ExportType = "program"